# Loop through a list of macros using jinja

Tags: jinja2

I want to know if its possible to loop through a list of macros in another macro in Jinja.

For example:

```
   {% set macro_list =  [macro_one,macro_two,macro_three] %} 
                      
   {% for macro in macro_list%}
   {{ macro(param) }} 
   {% endfor %}
```

Similar to how in python you can loop through a list of functions. Currently this does not work for me, as the macro name is being recognized as a string and not a reference to a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want references to macros?
Keep it simple and try to use macros with parameter, see [Jijnja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/?highlight=range#macros). Then you can use the code as the following example:

```
{% macro example(counter) %}
<p>Example {{ counter }}</p>
{% endmacro %}
{% for i in range(1, 4) %}
{{ example(i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives you:

```
<p>Example 1</p>
<p>Example 2</p>
<p>Example 3</p>
```

Comment: Thank you but I do really need the functionality of references to macros. I will be looping through a list of values to pass to the macros, but the list of macros i would need to pass them to changes depending on another parameter. Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem.

> You can also qualify a macro in your own project by prefixing it with your package name (this is mainly useful for package authors).

[source](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros)

An example:

```
[% set list = ["macro_one","macro_two]%]

{% for macro in list%}

    {{ package_name[macro](params) }}

{% endfor %}
```